# grep last 10 minutes of a log with bad data format

Tags: bash

my log has this date format at the beginning of each line:

```
2018 Sep 21 17:16:27:796
```

I need to grep the last 10 minutes of this log... any help?

my current experiments:

```
tenminutesago=$(date --date='10 minutes ago' +"%Y %b %e %H:%M:%S"):999
```

My idea was to convert the log format to a progressive number and then check everything greater than that number.

I see that the command: `date +"%Y %b %e %H:%M:%S"` gives a date in the same format of the log. The command: `date +"%Y%m%e%H%M%S"` gives a date in a progressive number `(201810041204019)`

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. This is not a coding service website. Show us, what you have done so far in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and you'll get help

Comment: I have a formula to calculate the date (in that formula) minus 10 minutes: tenminutesago=$(date --date='10 minutes ago' +"%Y %b %e %H:%M:%S"):999

Comment: sorry i'm new to this site, i'm trying to put a better comment, wait a sec

Comment: my curent experiments:  

`tenminutesago=$(date --date='10 minutes ago' +"%Y %b %e %H:%M:%S"):999  `
My idea was to convert the log format to a progressive number and then check everything greater than that number.  

I see that the command:  
`date +"%Y %b %e %H:%M:%S"  `
gives a date in the same format of the log.  
the command:  
`date +"%Y%m%e%H%M%S"  `  
gives a date in a progressive number (201810041204019)

Comment: problem is that there may be not exist a line with the exact "date minus 10 minutes"

Comment: It is incredible to see that this is one of the most frequently asked questions, but not a single one with a decent robust solution! Many questions could be tagged here as duplicates, but I don't want to do this since not a single one has a good solution!

Comment: @AndreaZ. First of, Welcome to Stack Overflow. If you say _**The last 10 minutes of the log file**_. Do you mean the last 10 minutes from the time now, or do you mean the last 10 minites since the time of the last entry in the log file?

Comment: hi @kvantour, basically I need to grep the errors from a big log, but only the errors happened the last 10 minutes. Every log line starts with a date/time format similar to "2018 Oct 04 12:04:01:978"

Comment: @AndreaZ. last 10 minutes from the current time (now) or the last 10 minutes in the log file. These are two different things. If the last time in the log file is "1982 Jan 20 15:32:21", then the last 10 minutes from now will result in no output, while the last 10 minutes from the last time in the log file will result in all entries between "1982 Jan 20 15:22:21" and "1982 Jan 20 15:32:21"

Comment: @kvantour i need to grep any "error" if happened the last 10 minutes from now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do

```
for i in {10..0}; do
    d=$(date -d "$i minutes ago" +'%Y %b %e %H:%M')
    grep "$d" logfile
done
```

This just divides the problem in the 11 sequential subtasks of getting all lines from 10 minutes ago, all lines from 9 minutes ago, etc. until the current minute.

Edit:

Here's an alternate solution that prints all lines following the first one where a date stamp from the last 10 minutes was found, not only those that carry a date stamp, and also avoids reading the file over from start several times:

```
# build a regex pattern that matches any date in the given format from the last 10 minutes
pattern=$(date +'%Y %b %e %H:%M')
for i in {10..1}; do
    pattern+=\|$(date -d "$i minutes ago" +'%Y %b %e %H:%M')
done

# print all lines starting from the first one that matches one of the dates in the pattern
awk "/$pattern/,0" logfile
```

Comment: While I like the approach a lot, I must say that this could fail on very very big files, where it takes more than 1 minute to process the file (imagine super slow nfs on TB file)

Comment: this seems working good! thank you, you saved my day. Over a log of 500kb the speed is acceptable, I will try with bigger logs.

Comment: i'm using your solution at the moment, it seems the easier and working one... there is just a little problem, some lines of the log do not start with the date and are ignored in this way. I know, this log is a total mess :-(

Comment: Where the date appears in the line should not matter as long as it has the same format. Can you post an example of a line that does not get matched even when you would expect it to?

Comment: hi Sam, I tested the first for and works fine but the output of course does not contain any line starting with the date. Sadly some lines of this log does not respect the same format, or maybe are continuation of the line before (but considered new lines in the log)

Answer (score 1):

Under the assumption that your loglines looks like

```
YYYY Bbb dd HH:MM:SS:sss Some random log message is here
```

You can do the following:

```
awk -v d=$(date -d "10 minutes ago" "+%Y %m %d %T") '
     { mm = sprintf("%0.2d",(index("JanFebMarAprMayJunJulAugSepOctNovDec",$2)+2)/3) 
       s = $1 " " mm " " $3 " "$4 }
     (s >= d){print}' logfile
```

The idea is to convert your date format into a Sortable format (Note that "Jan" < "Mar" but "Feb" < "Jan"). This is done by converting your month into a number with two digits and then compare it stringwise against the correct date.

Comment: this seems not working.  
In this moment I have the latest error in my log dated 2018 Oct 08 19:48:41:699.  
So, to try your code and catch that line I changed your code putting "9000 minutes ago" which produces the date 2018 Oct  4 06:12:15
The result is: awk: fatal: cannot open file `4' for reading (No such file or directory)

Comment: @AndreaZ. Could you please provide us with information about how your log-file looks like and type exactly the command you typed to obtain this error.

Comment: A line with an error:
`2018 Aug 02 11:41:18:662 GMT +0200 somestuffhere Error otherstuffhere` .
Little additional problem: some lines does not start with date.
So I `grep GMT|grep -i error on that log` .

Answer (score 0):

Try your current approach without the seconds and milliseconds.

```
tenminutesago=$(date --date='10 minutes ago' +"%Y %b %e %H:%M")
```

Is not exactly the last ten minutes to a second level, but I think it is enough for most of the cases. That will give you the first line in the log within the time window. Now you can get the total lines and subtract the line number of your previous grep, and then tail the file. The script could be like this:

```
LOGFILE="filename.log"
tenminutesago=$(date --date='9000 minutes ago' +"%Y %b %e %H:%M") # matching pattern
tlines=$(cat $LOGFILE | wc -l) # Total lines in file
let lines=$tlines-$(grep -n "$tenminutesago" $LOGFILE | grep -m 1 -oP "^[0-9]*" || echo $tlines) # lines after matching occurence
echo "$lines lines FOUND from the last X minutes"
tail -n $lines $LOGFILE # last lines in file
```

As suggested by [@Gem Taylor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8477999/gem-taylor), this could be reduced using +N option in tail.

```
LOGFILE="filename.log"
tenminutesago=$(date --date='9000 minutes ago' +"%Y %b %e %H:%M") # matching pattern
lines=$(grep -n "$tenminutesago" $LOGFILE | grep -m 1 -oP "^[0-9]*" || echo "0") # lines after matching occurence
echo "$lines lines FOUND from the last X minutes"
let lines -eq 0 && tail -n +$lines $LOGFILE # last lines in file if lines is not 0
```

Comment: this seems not working. I expanded the 10 minutes ago to 9000 minutes ago in order to catch an actual error present in the log. The result of the first line is: grep: Oct: No such file or directory
grep: 4: No such file or directory
grep: 06:13: No such file or directory
-bash: let: lines=3272-: syntax error: operand expected (error token is "-")

Comment: I updated the command and put quotes around the variable $tenminutesago. However, there will be an error if there is no entry in the log matching the value of $tenminutesago, I'm working on that case.

Comment: -bash: let: lines=3273-: syntax error: operand expected (error token is "-")

Comment: Could you post the value of $tenminutesago, and check that grep returns at least one matching line?

Comment: I updated the answer, now it is in a script form. I hope that helps

Comment: I think you can simplify the math by using `tail -n +linesfromstart`

Comment: Also, does this assume that there is an exact matching message from 10 minutes ago?

Comment: You could append a message with the date you want, and a dummy payload, sort the file, then grep for that dummy payload to get the line number.

Comment: to add more information: an example line with an error is: `2018 Aug 02 11:41:18:662 GMT +0200 somestuffhere Error otherstuffhere` .
Little additional problem: some lines does not start with date, and can contain an error... i know it's a mess!

Comment: The proposed answer only checks if the date pattern given by $tenminutesago matches the line, no matter the position. You can provide an example of an unmatched line. This answer will provide the lines corresponding to the last X minutes. Finding an error within those is another task.

Comment: @GVelascoh how can find also the lines between the interval but without a date?

Comment: I don't understand, Are you saying just giving the number of minutes? or removing the date from the matched lines?